# Replace element in nested list

Tags: haskell

I am working on a sudoku problem and trying to create a setBoardAt function that will update one of the values in one of the rows within the board to a new value using a setRowAt function.

```
setRowAt :: Sequence -> Int -> Int -> Sequence
setRowAt s i v = take i s ++ [v] ++ drop (i + 1) s

setBoardAt :: Board -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Board
setBoardAt b i j v = take i b ++ [setRowAt [s] j v | s <- b !! i] ++ drop (i + 1) b
```

In my main I can use the setRowAt function and return the expected results with what I have mapped out in the setBoardAt function

```
main = do

  args <- getArgs
  txt  <- readFile (head args)
  let board1 = getBoard txt
  print board1
  let seq1 = board1 !! 5
  print seq1
  let row1 = setRowAt seq1 2 5
  print row1
  let nboard1 = take 1 board1 ++ [row1] ++ drop (1 + 1) board1
```

results received are correct

```
[[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],[6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],[0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],[8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],[4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],[7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],[0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],[0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
[7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6]
[7,0,5,0,2,0,0,0,6]
```

but when I try to use the setBoardAt function using the same parameters and the nested setRowAt function, the row that I am manipulating returns incorrectly and I can't pinpoint why.

```
main = do

  args <- getArgs
  txt  <- readFile (head args)
  let board1 = getBoard txt
  print board1
  let test1 = setBoardAt board1 5 2 5
  print test1
```

```
[[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],[7,0,5,0,2,0,0,0,6],[0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],[8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],[4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],[7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],[0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],[0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
[[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],[6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],[0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],[8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],[4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],[7,5],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5],[2,5],[0,5],[0,5],[0,5],[6,5],[0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],[0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
```

Any suggestions or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: you should also add type synonyms you are using to the question detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using `setRowAt` correctly in `setBoardAt`.

What you are doing right now is taking each element from a row, and passing a list containing this element to setRowAt function. What you should instead do is something like following

```
setBoardAt b i j v = take i b ++ [setRowAt (b!!i) j v] ++ drop (i + 1) b
```